# Find all plane wave solutions of this wave equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I have the problem $$u_{tt}=C^2(u_{xx}+u_{yy}+u_{zz})$$ with initial condition $$u(x,y,z,0)=x-y+1$$
Therefore, I wish to find all functions $F(s)$ such that $$F(ax+by+cz-t)=u(x,y,z,t)$$ is a solution of my pde and $$F(ax+by+cz)=x-y+1 \:\:\:\:\:(*)$$
where $a^2+b^2+c^2=\frac{1}{C^2}$.

I thought about first finding a general form of the functions $F$ satisfying  $(*)$ and see where I can go from there. Any suggestions on how to proceed?

P.S.- I don't know how to solve a PDE using Fourier series

Comment: D'Alemberts formula?

Comment: @Mattos I'm only aware of d'Alembert formula for 1 dimensional wave equations. How would it apply here?

Comment: You're absolutely right, I totally forgot it didn't apply when $dim(X) > 1$. You'll probably want to look at the notes [here](https://web.stanford.edu/class/math220a/handouts/waveequation3.pdf).